# Is it possible to get all possible properties/parameters/etc attached to the client’s RDP session on server side?

Tags: remote-desktop, dpi

To understand the question below here is the situation:

I have a DPI related issue.

Two notebooks of different make/model connecting to the same Windows Server 2012R2 and executing same software with same steps. Last step shows a standard message box.

On one of the laptops the software window and font size shrinks when the message box displayed.

I narrowed down the problem to the DPI scaling handling (because modification of DPI related code in that software resolves the issue but this method may not be acceptable by other reasons).

Trials shows that when the RDP session opened on the "bad" notebook, disconnected and reconnected from the "good" one the problem still exists.

When the RDP session opened on the "good" notebook, disconnected and reconnected from the "bad" one the problem gone. So it looks like some setting attached to the RDP session during its initialization persist and is related to the problem.

I would like to figure out all possible properties/parameters/etc attached to the RDP session on server side.

I hope I can compare those two value sets assigned to the "good" and "bad" rdp sessions to make some progress in this issue.

**So here is my question**:

Can anybody help me with an appropriate command, tool or anything else which allows me to get these values? Maybe like the value of "smart sizing" which can be set in RDP file? How can I figure out with what smart sizing value setting initialized the actual rdp client the actual session? (the "smart sizing" stands here just for an example)

Comment: Do the answers in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/138140/change-the-default-resolution-of-remote-desktop-connection-mstsc) help with the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The post contains many configurable parameters but nothing about any way of showing the runtime values which I am looking for.