# Remote Desktop connect at host resolution vs default client resolution?

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, remote-control

I have a laptop that is HD 1920x1080 and a home desktop which is 4K 3840x2160.

I want to use remote desktop from my laptop, but see the full desktop 4K resolution.

I expect to have scroll bars to scroll the full resolution which the laptop cannot display.

Most third party apps like TeamViewer do this by default or allow zoom scaling for different resolutions.

Is there a way to have remote desktop behave this way as well?

Comment: Did you change the remote Display resolution in RDP (Pull down More Options in RDP) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Windows RDP, you can specify the remote desktop size and position in an RDP file.

[image]

[change-the-default-resolution-of-remote-desktop-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/138140/change-the-default-resolution-of-remote-desktop-connection-mstsc)

Comment: The resolution method only works for smaller resolutions. If I set it higher than the laptop, it just ignores the setting. Am I the only one with this?

Comment: I used a small resolution screen (ltaptop) to RDP to desktop at larger screen resolution and it worked fine. I refined my comment to an answer

Comment: I found it, the key was first to save the connection at a resolution other than full screen, as full screen just overrides it. Then the rdp file needs to be opened in notepad or other text editor to change the resolution and then it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the resolution slider as shown in the screen shot:

[image: Windows RDP]

I used my small screen Laptop (1366x768) and set the slider to full screen (farthest right) and was able to see the remote screen in a larger resolution (1920x1280).